# How do I reduce downtime of nginx ingress route when updating a destination pod?

Tags: performance, nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have set up an nginx ingres that routes traffic to specific deployments based on host.

> `host A --> Service A, host B --> Service B`

If I update the config for Deployment A, that update completes in *less than 2 seconds*. However, my nginx ingress goes down for host A after that and takes *5 to 7 seconds* to point to Service A with new pod.

How can I reduce this delay? Is there a way to speed up the performance of the nginx ingress so that it points to the new pod as soon as possible ( preferably less than 3 seconds?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/service-upstream` annotation to suppress the normal Endpoints behavior and use the Service directly instead. This has better integration with some deployment models but 5-7 seconds is extreme for ingress-nginx to be seeing the Endpoints update. There can be a short gap from when a pod is removed and when ingress-nginx sees the Endpoint removal. You usually fix that with a pre-stop hook that just sleeps for a few seconds to ensure by the time it actually exits, the Endpoint change has been processed everywhere.

Comment: Thank you. I applied the annotation and it's now down to 2 seconds. What a relief! Will read about the pre-stop hook as well - may be that improves it more!